# How can I setup StaticResourceExtension when unit testing a markup extension that relies on it?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq, markup-extensions

I have written a custom markup extension : `CoalesceResourceExtension`

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class CoalesceResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public CoalesceResourceExtension(string resources)
    {
        this.Resources = resources;
    }

    public string Separator { get; set; }

    [ConstructorArgument("resources")]
    public string Resources { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Resources != null)
        {
            foreach (string resourceName in Resources.Split(new[] { Separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (new StaticResourceExtension(resourceName).ProvideValue(serviceProvider) is object resource)
                    {
                        return resource;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I come to unit testing `CoalesceResourceExtension`, I can't seem to find a way to setup the `StaticResourceExtension` so that it will find the desired mocked resources. Is there a way I can setup things for the `StaticResourceExtension` to find my mocked resources?

Comment: With the current design no. You have to decouple `StaticResourceExtension` and  `CoalesceResourceExtension` to be able to inject the dependency...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider)`'s behaviour can be controlled via mocking the `IServiceProvider` passed by `CoalesceResourceExtension` to the `StaticResourceExtension` but you'll also need to mock all the services and objects from the services it uses : `IAmbientProvider`, `IXamlSchemaContextProvider`, `XamlSchemaContext`, `ResourceDictionary`, `XamlType`, `PropertyInfo` and `XamlMember`. I've built these mocks by watching what path the `StaticResourceExtension` was taking by both making the mocks strict and watching the exceptions they were throwing when meeting a member that wasn't setup and by looking at `StaticResourceExtension`'s source code.

Here's a method that builds the whole mocked `IServiceProvider` for every needed key + value pair passed in :

```
private IServiceProvider MockIServiceProviderForStaticResourceExtension(params KeyValuePair<object, object>[] resources)
{
    Mock<IServiceProvider> serviceProviderMock = new Mock<IServiceProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    Mock<IXamlSchemaContextProvider> xamlSchemaContextProviderMock = new Mock<IXamlSchemaContextProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    Mock<IAmbientProvider> ambientProviderMock = new Mock<IAmbientProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    Mock<XamlSchemaContext> xamlSchemaContextMock = new Mock<XamlSchemaContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    xamlSchemaContextMock.Setup(xsc => xsc.GetXamlType(It.IsAny<Type>())).Returns((Func<Type, XamlType>)(t => GetXamlTypeForType(t, xamlSchemaContextMock.Object)));
    ambientProviderMock.Setup(ap => ap.GetAllAmbientValues(null, false, It.IsAny<IEnumerable<XamlType>>(), It.IsAny<XamlMember[]>())).Returns((Func<IEnumerable<XamlType>, bool, IEnumerable<XamlType>, XamlMember[], IEnumerable<AmbientPropertyValue>>)GetAllAmbientValuesImplementation);
    xamlSchemaContextProviderMock.Setup(xscp => xscp.SchemaContext).Returns(xamlSchemaContextMock.Object);
    serviceProviderMock.Setup(s => s.GetService(typeof(IXamlSchemaContextProvider))).Returns(xamlSchemaContextProviderMock.Object);
    serviceProviderMock.Setup(s => s.GetService(typeof(IAmbientProvider))).Returns(ambientProviderMock.Object);
    serviceProviderMock.Setup(s => s.GetService(It.IsNotIn(typeof(IXamlSchemaContextProvider), typeof(IAmbientProvider)))).Returns(null);

    return serviceProviderMock.Object;

    IEnumerable<AmbientPropertyValue> GetAllAmbientValuesImplementation(IEnumerable<XamlType> ceilingTypes, bool searchLiveStackOnly, IEnumerable<XamlType> types, params XamlMember[] properties)
    {
        Mock<ResourceDictionary> resourceDictionaryMock = new Mock<ResourceDictionary>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        resourceDictionaryMock.Protected().Setup("OnGettingValue", false, ItExpr.Is<object>(o => resources.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(o))), ItExpr.Ref<object>.IsAny, ItExpr.Ref<bool>.IsAny).CallBase();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> kvp in resources)
        {
            resourceDictionaryMock.Object.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        Mock<AmbientPropertyValue> ambientPropertyValueMock = new Mock<AmbientPropertyValue>(MockBehavior.Strict, null, resourceDictionaryMock.Object);
        return new List<AmbientPropertyValue> { ambientPropertyValueMock.Object };
    }

    XamlType GetXamlTypeForType(Type t, XamlSchemaContext xamlSchemaContext)
    {
        Mock<XamlType> xamlTypeMock = new Mock<XamlType>(MockBehavior.Strict, t, xamlSchemaContext);
        xamlTypeMock.Protected().Setup<XamlMember>("LookupMember", true, "Resources", false).Returns((Func<string, bool, XamlMember>)LookupMemberImplementation);
        xamlTypeMock.Protected().Setup<XamlMember>("LookupMember", true, "BasedOn", false).Returns((Func<string, bool, XamlMember>)LookupMemberImplementation);
        xamlTypeMock.Setup(xt => xt.ToString()).CallBase();
        return xamlTypeMock.Object;

        XamlMember LookupMemberImplementation(string name, bool skipReadOnlyCheck)
        {
            Mock<PropertyInfo> propertyInfoMock = new Mock<PropertyInfo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            propertyInfoMock.Setup(pi => pi.Name).Returns(name);
            propertyInfoMock.Setup(pi => pi.DeclaringType).Returns(t);
            Mock<XamlMember> xamlMemberMock = new Mock<XamlMember>(MockBehavior.Strict, propertyInfoMock.Object, xamlSchemaContext);
            xamlMemberMock.Setup(xm => xm.ToString()).CallBase();
            return xamlMemberMock.Object;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While your solution likely works, I'd be extremely wary of it if I saw it in any code I was asked to work with. A common heuristic is "Don't mock stuff you don't own". You've got an awful lot of code there doing just that when providing an appropriate shim (satisfied by the real implementation at runtime, and a simulated one for testing - as suggested by @Keithernet) would keep things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a `ValueConverter`/`MarkupExtension` that was using `Application.Current.TryFindResource()`.

I created an `interface` called `IApplicationResourceResolver` with a method definition for `TryFindResource`.

Then I created an implementation of the interface called `ApplicationResourceResolver` that uses `Application.Current.TryFindResource()`.

In my converter/extension I have a public property:

```
public IApplicationResourceResolver Resolver {get; internal set; }
```

And in my constructor, I setup my default implementation:

```
public StringToResourceConverter()
{
    Resolver = new ApplicationResourceResolver();
}
```

Now, in my unit tests, I can set `Resolver` to a mocked up version to do tests!

You should be able to use this pattern to solve your issue. I hope this helps.

Comment: With this design my concern is that everytime you use the markup extension in xaml you have to specify that you want to use the `StaticResourceExtension` to resolve resources

Comment: You don't. In your constructor for your markup extension, you set the default implementation to use the StaticResourceExtension. It works as you designed it in XAML. You only use the public property in your unit tests.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a way to completely setup the `IServiceProvider` in order to have the `StaticResourceExtension`'s behaviour under my control